# Rebol / Red VID: why is close event immediately sent ?

Tags: rebol, red

I inspired from http://www.codeconscious.com/rebol/view-notes.html

I don't understand: why is close sent immediately: that's not what I want and I would expect it to be sent when I click on Window close

```
    query-on-close: func[face event][
        print "query-on-close"
        remove-event-func :query-on-close
        RETURN event    

    ]

    view layout [
        do [ insert-event-func :query-on-close ]
    ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
rebol []

query-on-close: func [face event][
    prin event/type prin " "
    either 'close = event/type [
        print "^/query-on-close handler now removed. Next close will now close this window"
        remove-event-func :f
        return none
    ][
        RETURN event    
    ]
]
f: insert-event-func :query-on-close

view layout [
    title "Test screen"
]
```

As written the first event you receive will print the message, and then remove the handler.  You need to test specifically for the *CLOSE* event.